# Resizing UITableView using ViewDeck

Tags: ios5, uitableview, resize, uistoryboard

I am trying to mimic the sliding table view functionality found in apps like Facebook. I am currently using the [Inferis/ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck) library. This works great as a slider but I can't figure out how to resize the table view to fit properly in the smaller space left by the slider without clipping.

Example:

[image: Example]

I have seen several other SO posts with similar questions but none that concisely answer how to resize a table view. Any examples or explanation would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For left oriented slider (i.e. slider that reveals a view to the left):

```
- (BOOL)viewDeckControllerWillOpenLeftView:(IIViewDeckController*)viewDeckController animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    self.tableView.frame = (CGRect) { self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                                      self.tableView.frame.origin.y, 
                                      320 - self.viewDeckController.leftLedge,
                                      self.tableView.frame.size.height };
    return YES;
}
```

For right oriented slider:

```
- (BOOL)viewDeckControllerWillOpenRightView:(IIViewDeckController*)viewDeckController animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
    self.tableView.frame = (CGRect) { self.viewDeckController.rightLedge,
                                      self.tableView.frame.origin.y, 
                                      320 - self.viewDeckController.rightLedge,
                                      self.tableView.frame.size.height };
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to resize a `UITableViewController`, but you can create a `UITableView` inside the `UIViewController`, and resize the `UITableView`.

Comment: I don't mention resizing a UITableViewController in my question or my answer, only resizing a UITableView.